# Gazebo ros control position controller joints problem

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros-kinetic, gazebo-ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am currently working on a project using a vehicle of type EasyMile Ez10 and I have problems when it comes to control both the steering and linear joints. I am currently using Gazebo 7 with ROS Kinetic.

The urdf model in Gazebo has 8 joints and transmissions: 4 continuous (velocity controller) to move the model forward and 4 revolute (position controller) to turn each wheel (like a double Ackermann in which the back wheels mirror the front ones); The description tree of the wheels is like this one:

[image: image description]

and this is the model:

[image: image description]

The problem arises when I try to command the joints. If I try to spin the steer joints, the effort applied to each joint by the controller is shared between the parent (axle_joint for steering wheels) and the child (linear joints for movement), hence, the steer joint spin properly but the linear joint moves like if I applied also an effort to it. An example of that behavior can be found here:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RVhHscatYyAEO0MYfpE7jQ9p_h4FfrsI

I think is a problem of contacts with the floor and the mass of the model (2000 kg) but I tried to modify the floors properties and ODE parameter with no avail.

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Ok, thanks for the suggestions. I have added new links for resources. Since I do not have enough karma I am not able to post them here direcly.

This is the urdf regarding the wheels of the model:

```
<robot name="wheel" xmlns:xacro="http://www.ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <xacro:property name="M_PI" value="3.1415926535897931" />
  <!-- Wheels -->
 
  <xacro:macro name="cylinder_inertia" params="m r h">
    <inertia  ixx="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}" ixy = "0.0" ixz = "0.0"
              iyy="${m*r*r/2}" iyz = "0.0"
              izz="${m*(3*r*r+h*h)/12}" /> 
  </xacro:macro>
 
  <xacro:macro name="rubber_wheel" params="prefix parent wheel_radius wheel_width wheel_mass orientation *origin">
  
    <!--WHEEL TIRE -->
    <link name="${prefix}_wheel">
      <visual>
        <!-- HIGH RESOLUTION WHEELS -->
        <xacro:if value="${orientation == 0}"> 
          <origin xyz="0 ${-wheel_width/2} ${-wheel_radius}" rpy="0 0 ${orientation}" />
        </xacro:if>
        <xacro:if value="${orientation == M_PI}"> 
          <origin xyz="0 ${wheel_width/2} ${-wheel_radius}" rpy="0 0 ${orientation}" />
        </xacro:if>
        <geometry>
            <mesh scale="0.061 0.061 0.061" filename="file:///$(find ares_description)/meshes/wheels/wheel.dae"/>
        </geometry>
      </visual>      
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="${M_PI/2} 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <cylinder length="${wheel_width}" radius="${wheel_radius}" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>    
      <inertial>
        <mass value="${wheel_mass}" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
        <cylinder_inertia  m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}" /> <!-- macro defined at the beginning of this document -->
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Virtual link for two joints -->
    <link name="${prefix}_wheel_axle">    
      <inertial>
        <mass value="${wheel_mass}" />
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" />
        <cylinder_inertia  m="${wheel_mass}" r="${wheel_radius}" h="${wheel_width}" /> <!-- macro defined at the beginning of this document -->
      </inertial>
    </link>

    <!-- Wheel steer joint -->
    <joint name="${prefix}_wheel_steer_joint" type="revolute">
      <parent link="${parent}"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_wheel_axle"/>
      <xacro:insert_block name="origin" />
      <axis xyz="0 0 1" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <limit lower="-0.31" upper="0.31" effort="20000" velocity="0.5"/>
      <joint_properties damping="2.0" friction="1.0"/>
    </joint>

    <!-- Wheel linear joint -->
    <joint name="${prefix}_wheel_joint" type="continuous">
      <parent link="${prefix}_wheel_axle"/>
      <child link="${prefix}_wheel"/>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy = "0 0 0"/>
      <axis xyz="0 1 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <limit effort="20000" velocity="20"/>
      <joint_properties damping="1.0" friction="1.0"/>
    </joint>


    <!-- Transmission is important to link the joints and the controller (see summit_xl_control/config/summit_xl_control.yaml)-->
    <transmission name="${prefix}_wheel_joint_trans">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="${prefix}_wheel_joint">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/VelocityJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="${prefix}_wheel_joint_motor">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
     </transmission>

    <transmission name="${prefix}_wheel_joint_trans_steer">
      <type>transmission_interface/SimpleTransmission</type>
      <joint name="${prefix}_wheel_steer_joint">
        <hardwareInterface>hardware_interface/PositionJointInterface</hardwareInterface>
      </joint>
      <actuator name="${prefix}_wheel_joint_motor_steer">
        <mechanicalReduction>1</mechanicalReduction>
      </actuator>
     </transmission>

    <gazebo reference="${prefix}_wheel">
      <mu1 value="1.0"/>
      <mu2 value="1.0"/>
      <kp value="1000000000.0" />
      <kd value="1.0" />
      <fdir1 value="0 0 0"/>
      <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
      <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    </gazebo>

    <gazebo reference="${prefix}_wheel_axle">
      <mu1 value="1.0"/>
      <mu2 value="1.0"/>
      <kp value="1000000000.0" />
      <kd value="1.0" />
      <fdir1 value="0 0 0"/>
      <turnGravityOff>false</turnGravityOff>
      <minDepth>0.001</minDepth>
    </gazebo>
  
  </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328721/gazebo-ros-control-position-controller-joints-problem/) by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1695 on 2019-07-17

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-17**:
You need to update your sharing settings for the links. We don't have access.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-17**:\

> You need to update your sharing settings for the links. We don't have access.

Ideally, screenshots are attached to the question directly and urdf/xacro/code and terminal output are copy-pasted into the text as well.

And if possible: a (short) gif of a video would also be preferred over a google drive link, as those typically disappear.

I've given OP sufficient karma to do that.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-17**:
I've just fixed your karma. For some reason it got deducted earlier. You should now be able to post the images as well.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-17**:
One quick comment. You describe the continuous wheel drive joints as linear. Prismatic joints are usually described as linear, so this is a confusing comment. Maybe wheel 'drive' would be clearer.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-07-17**:
Ok. The joints marked as "cont." are supposed to be the ones that moves the model (I called it linear control but it can be changed to be more precise).

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-17**:
It's possible the effect you're seeing is caused by friction from the floor. Can you try lifting the robot off the ground so the wheel is in mid air and testing this again.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-07-17**:
Yes, actually when the model is in the air the control is just smooth. I tried to change ODE parameter of the floor and the joints but the effect persists.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-07-17**:
@Weasfas: off-topic, but is that a wepod?

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-17**:
Does the problem persist if the drive wheel controller is active (it's holding the velocity at zero)? Given this is caused by the ground back-driving the wheel is this really a problem?

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-07-17**:
@gvdhoorn Yes it is a wepod.

@PeteBlackerThe3rd The controller being used is [four_wheel_steering_controller](http://wiki.ros.org/four_wheel_steering_controller). It is a problem when it comes to controlling the platform since a change of the steering angle affects the velocity of each of the "drive" joints.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2019-07-18**:
Given that a real robot may well experience a similar effect of the wheels being back-driven when steering I think the simulation is doing exactly what you want it to. Making your controllers deal with that behaviour would be the solution I'd recommend in this case.

**Comment by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) on 2019-07-18**:
Ok, I will then focus on the control of the platform. Thanks for the help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I will add as an answer the approach I implemented to cope with this problem if someone finds this in the future. The problem comes when Gazebo tries to compute the proper contact solutions when the wheels come into contact with the ground. I think the equations used in my particular environment lack of proper solutions thus the contacts joints generated by Gazebo exert wrong efforts as a result of applying new velocities to the joints. To solve this problem I tried several things:

1. Change wheel collision primitive. Instead of a cylinder the collision needs to be a sphere, thus generating a single contact and providing proper solution to the equations.
2. Change wheel collision by multiple ones. Instead of having one collision you can place multiple cylindrical collision providing more contacts along the wheel width and thus more balanced set of  solutions.
3. Tune ODE collision an friction parameters (kp, kd, mu1, mu2 ...) as well as ODE physics engine properties in the world file (iters, cmf, erp ...).
4. Adjust PID gains to be consistent with you simulation physics. I noted that velocity and position controllers have strange behaviors with high P and D gains (I was forced to use those high values because my model has a huge mass). Hence, tuning experimentally those values may help to achieve a smoother control.

I tested all these approaches and a mix of them seems to work with my model. The thing I am not completely sure is why increasing contacts helps the simulation. Is because I provide more equations to find easy solutions or because forces counteract when exerting new velocities to the joints?.

Cheers!

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2019-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0